# How long does it take for a tag synonym to be approved?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

A while-ish ago, I suggested a tag synonym [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/novel/synonyms). After this while-ish, it's still stayed at 0 votes. While this could mean that its upvotes and downvotes canceled out, I really doubt that because it seems unlikely, given what the actual synonym is. First of all, I want to know how long it takes before someone actually votes on it. Second of all, *please vote on it!*

Comment: Usually forever, since hardly anyone is aware of the synonym list, let alone able to vote for synonyms, let alone aware that they're able to, let alone checking that list to do so.

Comment: @TARS On that note, I know the dashboard exists but it still took me a while searching around to remember how to get to it so I could add the link in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Tag synonym suggestions are largely ignored unless specifically raised.

There's no easy way to navigate to the tag synonyms page, and I'd guess very few if any people regularly check for tag synonym suggestions. Also the system won't automatically bring any proposed tag synonym to the attention of users able to review it (e.g. there's no review queue for tag synonym suggestions). So if you just propose a synonym and let it lie, it's very unlikely to be seen. You could ask for help in chat, or better on meta, to get a tag synonym approved.

It's often useful to get moderator help for tag synonymisation. The *merge* tool (only available to diamond mods) is usually better to use than the synonymisation tool, since it leaves no trace of the synonym tag hanging around on old questions even though it can't be added to new ones. For very clear cases you *might* consider raising a mod flag, but apparently it's possible that someone might consider two tags "clearly synonymous" which actually aren't at all. That brings me to the second point ...

### Your particular suggestion was very wrong and has been rejected.

It's no longer visible on the page you linked to in the OP, but from comments and the other answer here I gather that you proposed [novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel) as a synonym of [books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) or vice versa. As has already been explained to you in comments, these two are not remotely synonymous, either as tags on SFF.SE or even as English language words. Many books are not novels, so the words are not the same, and for our site it's useful to break down the general [books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) tag into subcategories like [novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel) and [short-stories](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories) with their own tags. So the community rightly downvoted your tag synonym suggestion enough that it disappeared.

Comment: _”There's no easy way to navigate to the tag synonyms page”_ If you mean the dashboard, there is, it’s just very easily missed. IIRC it’s on the tags page at the bottom as a tiny link.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I don't count that as an easy way to navigate to it ;-)

Comment: Me neither for some reason my brain parsed out _”easy”_ and I just read it as _”There’s no way...”_

Answer (score 4):

Tag synonyms take an indeterminate amount of time to be voted on due to how they work. As far as I know there is no automatic system that notifies anyone to vote on a tag synonym request. People need to visit the tag page or [Tag Synonym Dashboard](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested).

*Then* that user needs [an answer score for that tag of at least 5](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms):

> Users with a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms.

The best way to speed up the process is to either ask a meta question on it, preferably beforehand asking if it is a good idea, ask in chat *or* flag for moderator attention. I would use the last option sparingly though and where it is essentially a clear cut case.

---

#### A note about this request

This request should get declined as the tags have different uses. Just in regards to [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions [novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel) is used when trying to identify a novel and [books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) is used when identifying a series *or* when we don't know what sub type of book it is i.e. they say book but don't specify between novel, novella, short story, etc.

Comment: Hate to disagree, but "novel" is considered a synonym of "book" by https://thesaurus.com

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath The _words_ ___might___ be synonymous but that doesn't mean their usages as _tags_ on SFF are.

Comment: Uh...not even the words are *remotely* synonymous. A genuine dictionary or encyclopedia might be more helpful there than some random internet thesaurus app made for poets seeking word recommendations.

Comment: @TARS - thesaurus.com is a widely recognized source for finding synonyms. That's what a thesaurus does. It gives you synonyms...

Comment: "book" also applies to anthologies, picture books (e.g. *Spacecraft 2000 to 2100 AD*) and any auxiliary works like *The Science of Discworld*.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath You need to realise that tag synonyms ___aren't___ word synonyms, there is a distinct difference between them. The tag usages need to align not just the word meaning, which arguably doesn't in this case anyway.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - I'm not disagreeing with you. I'm disagreeing with TARS...

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath I know your comment was a reply to his one.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath Still a thesaurus has another purpose and accuracy requirement than a genuine word definition. I'm not sure you really want to argue every book is a novel and every novel is a book, since I see that not feasible. The terms just aren't synonymous, their usage in song lyrics and colloquial talk nothwithstanding. But anyway, I agree that this is ultimately tangential to the actual meta discussion.